# Python selenium relative XPATHs

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying scrape some prices off a Diablo II website.

I'm having some issues separating prices after the scrape.
I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://traderie.com/diablo2resurrected/product/3382986705?prop_Platform=PC&prop_Mode=softcore&makeOffer=false')

# Close cookie popup
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tyche_cmp_modal"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/a'))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@style,'capitalize')]")))
time.sleep(1)

offers = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "listing-product-info")

for offer in offers:
    name = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@href,'profile')]")
    selling = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@href,'listing')]")

    selling_text = selling.text
    selling_text = selling_text[:selling_text.find('Rune')-1]
    
    prices = offer.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@style,'capitalize')]")
    print('-----',name.text,'-----')
    print("selling:\n",selling_text,"\nfor:")

    for price in prices:
        print(price.text)
    

# Close page
driver.close()
```

The issue is that the I'm not able to scrape the "ORs" which separate different price options in each individual offer.

I have tried a few different approaches unsuccessfully:

1. From offer, I use the divs: `/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div` to dive down the XPATH braches untill I finally reach the OR that I need. However, seeing as the OR's are not at the same levels, this doesn't work.
2. I redefine prices as: `prices = offer.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//a[contains(@style,'capitalize')]../..")` Which should get me to the grandparent of the said div? This doesn't work either.

TL:DR: What is the best way to print the whole line of text e.g. `2 x Lo Rune OR` instead of just `2 x Lo Rune`

**ELABORATION:**

I have made a snipped with colorcoding of the Xpaths I have and what I need.

[image: Colorcoded Xpath tree]

From this it can be seen that my offers definition is colored red. I "dive" into this definition with selling and prices (blue and yellow).

Instead of retrieving the prices marked in yellow, I'd like to retrieve the price including the OR marked in red.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on _"ORs"_ with example which you are not able to scrape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this part of your code:

```
    for price in prices:
        print(price.text)
```

You are printing the text each element selected by the xpath `".//a[contains(@style,'capitalize')]"` within each element selected by the class name `"listing-product-info"`.

The problem is that the `"OR"` text is located at the **parent** element *of* the parent of each element stored in the `price` variable. Observe:

[image]

A simple fix would be to simply get the text of the parent element of the parent element of each of the elements in the `prices` list. The xpath `".."` will select the parent element of an element:

```
    for price in prices:
        parent = price.find_element(By.XPATH, '..') # get parent element
        print(parent.find_element(By.XPATH, '..').text) # get text of parent element of parent element
```

Below, I omitted many parts of your code just for easier visualization of the change. But of course, all you'll have to do is replace your `for price in prices` loop with the one above:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://traderie.com/diablo2resurrected/product/3382986705?prop_Platform=PC&prop_Mode=softcore&makeOffer=false')
time.sleep(1)
offers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("listing-product-info")

for offer in offers:
    name = offer.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@href,'profile')]")
    selling = offer.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@href,'listing')]")
    selling_text = selling.text
    selling_text = selling_text[:selling_text.find('Rune') - 1]
    prices = offer.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@style,'capitalize')]")
    print('-----', name.text, '-----')
    print("selling:\n", selling_text, "\nfor:")
    for price in prices:
        parent = price.find_element_by_xpath('..')
        print(parent.find_element_by_xpath("..").text)

# Close page
driver.close()
```

Output:

```
----- math30 -----
selling:
 1 X Sur 
for:
1 X Lo Rune
1 X Ohm Rune
----- Fark4290 -----
selling:
 1 X Sur 
for:
1 X The Stone Of Jordan
----- MateuszGlesmann29170 -----
selling:
 1 X Sur 
for:
1 X The Stone Of Jordan
----- Shenk -----
selling:
 1 X Sur 
for:
2 X Ist Rune
1 X Lo Rune
1 X Ohm Rune
----- Piterundefined11939 -----
selling:
 1 X Sur 
for:
1 X Lo Rune
2 X Vex Rune   OR
3 X Ohm Rune   OR
6 X Vex Rune   OR
12 X Gul Rune
----- Piterundefined11939 -----
selling:
 1 X Sur 
for:
1 X Ber Rune   OR
1 X Jah Rune   OR
2 X Lo Rune
...
```

Of course, the output continues, so I put `"..."` just to indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
prices = offer.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[div/img[@class='listing-img']]")
```

With `div[div/img[@class='listing-img']]` you get the grandparent element that contains the entire text.

Here is the output:

```
root@92fa00e3f091:/opt/code# python seleniumtest.py
----- OndřejMartinec43989 -----
selling:
 1 X Sur
for:
1 X Ber Rune
----- Baboob -----
selling:
 2 X Sur
for:
1 X Jah Rune
----- Benson97863 -----
selling:
 1 X Sur
for:
1 X Lo Rune
1 X Vex Rune
1 X Ohm Rune
----- sasuke9928 -----
selling:
 2 X Sur
for:
2 X Ist Rune
1 X Ber Rune
----- NEFHALEMASD -----
selling:
 1 X Sur
for:
1 X Lo Rune
1 X Zod Rune
----- DukeDinh9179 -----
selling:
 1 X Sur
for:
1 X Lo Rune
1 X Ohm Rune   OR
1 X The Stone Of Jordan
----- neveng -----
selling:
 2 X Sur
for:
1 X Ist Rune
1 X Jah Rune
----- zod33 -----
selling:
 1 X Sur
for:
3 X Ohm Rune
----- Piterundefined11939 -----
selling:
 1 X Sur
for:
1 X Ber Rune   OR
1 X Jah Rune   OR
2 X Lo Rune
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for offer in offers:
    a_tags = offer.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    for at in a_tags:
        if "listings" in at.get_attribute("href"):
            print("-----", at.text, "-----")
        elif "profile" in at.get_attribute("href"):
            print("selling:\n", at.text, "\nfor:")
        elif "product" in at.get_attribute("href"):
            print(at.text)
```

Comment: I see the idea, but as the div containing the OR doesn't have an href, I need to access the grandparent of that in order to include the OR in the print.